# Google KMS giving error when decrypting data

Tags: c#, asp.net, encryption, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-kms

When i try to decrypt my data using the Google KMS i am getting this error. Below is my code for the decryption. The error is hitting on the line where there is `string plaintext`. Thanks in advance

**Code**

```
    public static string Encrypt(string plaintext)
    {
        KeyManagementServiceClient client = KeyManagementServiceClient.Create();
        //projects/progforthecloudt2020/locations/global/keyRings/pfckeyring001/cryptoKeys/pfckeys
        CryptoKeyName kn = CryptoKeyName.FromUnparsed(new 
        Google.Api.Gax.UnparsedResourceName("GOOGLE RESOURCE ID REMOVED"));
        string cipher = client.Encrypt(kn, ByteString.CopyFromUtf8(plaintext)).Ciphertext.ToBase64();

        return cipher;
    }

    public static string Decrypt(string cipher)
    {
        KeyManagementServiceClient client = KeyManagementServiceClient.Create();
        CryptoKeyName kn = CryptoKeyName.FromUnparsed(new Google.Api.Gax.UnparsedResourceName("GOOGLE RESOURCE ID REMOVED"));
        string plaintext = client.Decrypt(kn, ByteString.CopyFromUtf8(cipher)).Plaintext.ToBase64();

        return plaintext;
    }
```

**Error**

```
Grpc.Core.RpcException: 'Status(StatusCode=InvalidArgument, Detail="Decryption failed: the ciphertext is invalid.")'
```

Comment: Have a look at the documentation [Encrypting and decrypting data with a symmetric key](https://cloud.google.com/kms/docs/encrypt-decrypt) and check examples for C# in section [Decrypt](https://cloud.google.com/kms/docs/encrypt-decrypt#decrypt).

Answer (score 2):

You’re base64 encoding the result of your encryption call, but then you aren’t base64 decoding it in your decrypt call. You shouldn’t need to base64 encode the data.

```
public static void Encrypt(string projectId, string locationId, string keyRingId, string cryptoKeyId, string plaintextFile, string ciphertextFile)
{
    KeyManagementServiceClient client = KeyManagementServiceClient.Create();
    CryptoKeyName cryptoKeyName =
        new CryptoKeyName(projectId, locationId, keyRingId, cryptoKeyId);

    byte[] plaintext = File.ReadAllBytes(plaintextFile);
    EncryptResponse result = client.Encrypt(cryptoKeyName, ByteString.CopyFrom(plaintext));

    // Output encrypted data to a file.
    File.WriteAllBytes(ciphertextFile, result.Ciphertext.ToByteArray());
    Console.Write($"Encrypted file created: {ciphertextFile}");
}


public static void Decrypt(string projectId, string locationId, string keyRingId, string cryptoKeyId, string ciphertextFile, string plaintextFile)
{
    KeyManagementServiceClient client = KeyManagementServiceClient.Create();
    CryptoKeyName cryptoKeyName =
        new CryptoKeyName(projectId, locationId, keyRingId, cryptoKeyId);

    byte[] ciphertext = File.ReadAllBytes(ciphertextFile);
    DecryptResponse result = client.Decrypt(cryptoKeyName, ByteString.CopyFrom(ciphertext));

    // Output decrypted data to a file.
    File.WriteAllBytes(plaintextFile, result.Plaintext.ToByteArray());
    Console.Write($"Decrypted file created: {plaintextFile}");
}
```

Comment: Can you show me what i need to add exactly or change cause i already saw that Google Example. Thanks

Comment: Don’t base64. You’re double base64 encoding.

Comment: so i remove the part `PlainText.ToBase64();`

Comment: Either change the return type from string to byte[] and drop all base64, OR change your decrypt function to base64 _DECODE_ the input value first, before attempting to decrypt.